# Why can the version table only have two columns?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, documentation, documentation-proposals

I've just created a version table with a header like that:

[image: header]

because it makes sense: It provides a good overview about how things changed over time.

**However** I got this:

[image: error]

which is not well documented at all. I suspect the two entries are version and release date as seen in the mardown help. There's no explanation that these two entries (and only these two entries) are valid for the version table.

Adding some dummy data to the second column results in:

[image: date]

I doubt that anybody will be interested in the release dates. Why bother bloating the documentation with that? And why can't there be more information that's actually useful?

As of now, the version table is only good as a definition of version numbers and release dates, but being displayed as such, it's not very useful.

**Suggestion: Allow additional columns for additional information in version tables.**

Comment: You can have more than two columns: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/flask/790/introduction-to-flask#t=201607271909507724986&a=versions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Version tables already support multiple columns, that error message should be tweaked.  I'll get that done in the next build.

The actual requirements are:

- at least two columns
- the first column must be the version name
- the last column must be a release date, in yyyy-MM-dd format

(You can also have multiple tables, prefaced by a heading, if there are multiple "tracks" of versions for tag [like .NET Micro, or Java ME])

The need for a name is obvious I think.

The release date is so we have an agreed upon way to reliably order versions.  In a perfect world we'd use the version names themselves, but not everyone uses semantic versioning.  We went with release date instead of an ordinal (implicit or explicit) because it can be generally agreed upon, and insertions won't mangle anything.